# Xamarin.Mac Using Arrow Keys to select TableView cells

Tags: c#, xamarin.mac

I am looking to add some creature comforts to my table view. So far things are going well, but I would love to add some spreadsheet functionality like using arrow keys to traverse the sheet. Right now the default behavior is row selection using the keys, there wasn't anything that stood out on the Apple Developer documentation.

My current thoughts are to use event handlers (tho I have no experience) to detect the arrow keys, but I'm hoping there is a simpler option.

Thanks,

Comment: Is this application targeting a iOS phone or a computer (mac OS)? if you're targeting a phone, you probably don't have to do this. If on a iMac or MacBook, check this link
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fc8d198a-2012-43a1-8062-5ff82973b06d/how-can-i-detect-key-events-in-xamarinforms?forum=xamarinforms

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.